# EC2: Should I restart when I get a "*** System restart required ***"?

Tags: apt, restart, amazon-ec2, aws

When I log into my machines after an `apt-get upgrade`s, I often get this message:

```
  System load:  0.06              Processes:           86
  Usage of /:   28.3% of 7.75GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 6%                IP address for eth0: 172.31.41.38
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud


*** System restart required ***
```

Obviously, restarting a production server is not something I'm keen to do very often.

Why is `*** System restart required ***`? What risks do I take if I don't restart it?

Comment: @Parto My question is more specific than the one you've linked to - I am asking about EC2 servers.

Comment: EC2 servers are a just subclass of all other Ubuntu systems. The answer is the same.

Comment: I think the aim of Adam is actually to find an answer to: *"what do I need to do to ensure maximum uptime?"* but correct me if I'm wrong.